# Extension function parameters or return values which have Clr type 'XmlQualifiedName' are not supported trying to use FILE.ReceivedFileName

Tags: c#, .net, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I am creating import application using BizTalk.
I have created File schema and Database tables schema and map those schemas as below:
[image]

Also, I want Filename into the table so I created scripting functiod and its scripts as below:
[image]

Now I am validating and testing map but it is giving me below error:
**Extension function parameters or return values which have Clr type 'XmlQualifiedName' are not supported.**

Please see below SS for Orchestration:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is basically saying you can't call that method the way it is defined.  Are you just trying to get the filename?  Are you executing this map in a port or in an Orchestration?

Comment: I successfully to get content of XML data in database but not able to get filename. I created Orchestration and created map from Orchestration. Thanks

Comment: What adapter are you using to get the file?  If it is a WCF-SQL adapter, then there is no Filename.  Only File or FTP adapters will give you a filename.

Comment: There is File Adapter on receive port side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it looks you might have some repeating nodes, and you can't promote or distinguish a field that occurs multiple times, do the following.

1. Create an internal schema where the fname only occurs once.
2. Distinguish that field by right clicking anywhere on the schema tree, select Promote, Show Promotions
   [image]
3. Select the field to distinguish (e.g. fName), make sure the tab is in Distinguished Fields (the default), click the Add button, click the OK Button
   [image]
4. Have a map from your rcv_msg to the internal_msg wich either sets a default value to that field or use a functoid like the String Concatenate to set a default value. This is so that the map creates that element.
   [image]
5. Inside your construct shape in your Orchestration add a Message Assignment shape following your transform shape.
   [image]
6. In the assignment shape have code like the following `internal_msg.fName = rcv_msg(FILE.ReceivedFileName);`
   [image]
   [image]
7. Map from the internal schema to your snd_msg, you can either execute that in the Orchestration or in the Send Port.

Comment: I edited my question so please review orchestration so you can have idea what is in orchestration.

Comment: While I am testing internal map I am getting following error: D:\Vijay_Work\NetLink\Task Data\Sample Catalog Import\1_Record.xml: error btm1046: Output validation error: The element 'CatalogImport' in namespace 'http://ImportCatalogDataSample.InternalCatalog' has invalid child element 'SupplierID' in namespace 'http://ImportCatalogDataSample.InternalCatalog'. List of possible elements expected: 'fname' in namespace 'http://ImportCatalogDataSample.InternalCatalog'.

Comment: If I set default value like you said, then I am getting only that default value in output, but I want filename instead of default.